# Add class to all children except first child

Tags: jquery

I have some html where I want to add a class to all children except the first child.

```
    <div class="test">
        <div class="different">title</div>
        <div class="same">a</div>
        <div class="same">b</div>
        <div class="same">c</div>
    </div>
```

with the below js

```
<script>
$(".test").children().each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass("eg_" + (i+1));
});
</script>
```

see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/HaH2y/

I want every child div of test except the first one to get the class "eg_" + (i+1) and I can't seem to get this working?

I have seen a few similar examples see the eg below but can't quite work it out from this.  Where have I gone wrong here?

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/y9bEG/11/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to filter and a [callback](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to set the precise class :

```
$('.test > div:gt(0)').addClass(function(i){
      return 'eg_'+(i+2);
});
```

(it's not clear in your question if you need `i`, `i+1` or `i+2`)

Answer (score 2):

Try checking index

```
<script>
$(".test").children().each(function(i) {

if(i!=0){ // check the first index and add 
   $(this).addClass("eg_" + (i+1));
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try  this:

```
$(".test").children().each(function(i) {
    if (i>0) {
        $(this).addClass("eg_" + (i));
    } else {
        i++;
    }
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
          ##  This code can help answer, and I completed my friends   
    ##





         <div id="list3">
               <ul class="NewFilm">
               <li>test1</li>
               <li>test2</li>
               <li>test3</li>
               <li>test4</li>
               <li>test5</li>
               </ul>
              </div> 
        <script>
       $("li:lt(5)").addClass("eg_1");
</script>
         <style>
        .eg_1, .eg_2, .eg_3 {color:red;}
        </style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/moslem68/oo907b6s/1/